# How to place subdomain in the sitemap

Tags: seo, google-analytics, web-crawlers, sitemap, subdomain

A site made this sitemap for me:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<script>window._wordtune_extension_installed = true;</script>
<!--  created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com  -->
<url>
<loc>http://delightpen.art/</loc>
<lastmod>2023-05-30T16:29:49+00:00</lastmod>
</url>
</urlset>
```

But my site has a subdomain which is actually a blog and is not mentioned here:

`http://contents.delightpen.art/`

How should I place my blog in the sitemap?

regards,

Answer (score 2):

A sitemap contains all pages, not domains.  Just replicate the `<url>` entry like this, for every page

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<script>window._wordtune_extension_installed = true;</script>
<!--  created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com  -->
<url>
<loc>http://delightpen.art/</loc>
<lastmod>2023-05-30T16:29:49+00:00</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://contents.delightpen.art/</loc>
<lastmod>2023-05-30T16:29:49+00:00</lastmod>
</url>
</urlset>
```